# Accessing a non-editable hidden field in Angular

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, authentication

So I have a unique situation. I have a small angular app that lives inside of a legacy ASP.NET webforms app (the header and the footer). The user still authenticates via Webforms, there is no token service currently implemented.

However when Angular submits a form the back end needs the JSON to contain a `CreatedBy` value which is equal to the `CurrentUserId`. This value is accessible via a hidden field that looks like: 
`<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$contentPage$CurrentUserId" id="CurrentUserId" value="326">`

The other curveball is this hidden input tag lives outside of the `<div ng-app> </div>` div.

I'm a little stumped to how I would accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just `document.querySelector('#CurrentUserId').value` ???

Comment: Yup! So easy it was hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can register this value as constant just on page: `angular.module('myApp').constant('currentUserId', '<%= CurrentUserId.Value %>');`

Comment: Thanks! How would you access this in a controller though? Say I need to post a form with this value. Would I use something like `$rootScope.currentUserId` ?

Comment: add it as a dependency in a controller i.e. `function ($scope, currentUserId){} ` "constants" are syntactic sugar for services. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What are the advantages of using this method as opposed to just a standard `document.getElementById(CurrentUserId).value` ?